# How to get a bordered picture with two different colors

Tags: html, css

I have a picture in HTML and I want to set a border with 2 different colors (with different width), here is an example:

[image]

So far I have this code:

```
<style>
#stream
        {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0px 20px;
            border-left-color: #00b000;
            border-right-color: red;
            border-left-image: linear-gradient( 0deg, blue 80%, red 80.001%); /*Not working*/
        }
</style>
<img id="stream" src="bla.png">
```

I tried using a linear gradient but it's not as expected (I didn't want a fade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the before element and just put a rectangle behind the image: https://jsfiddle.net/y1e0wmgm/

```
.multiborder {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #00f;
        height: 20%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    img {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Btw, you had a great idea with the gradient background. Just have to make the color change more sharp: https://jsfiddle.net/martingottweis/y1e0wmgm/1/

```
background: linear-gradient( 0deg, blue 80%, red 80.001%);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer (and your correction about my English's mistakes), I thought about my problem and I updated the picture. The exact thing I want to develop is a RC car with a camera (the image is the stream of the camera), and the 2 borders represent the distance from the RC car to an obstacle (works like a lidar), like a progress bar but vertical, but every thing I try doesn't work, I am really sorry about my English, i hope you understood

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/martingottweis/y1e0wmgm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS3 `border-image` property and select a suitable image to have "wrapped around the picture."

See: [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) and [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/)
You can also use the above details with an SVG syntax to create dynamic border images,

So:

**CSS**
The Border.png is a small file of two colours as
detailed in your question image.

```
.module {
  border-image-source: url('/path/to/border.png');
  border-image-width: 20;
  border-image-outset: 1;
  border-image-repeat: space;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <img src="bla.png" class='module'>
```